# String to JSON Compare using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas' DataFrames. I have a case like this after merging 2 files:
`fr.item = "ipod"`; `fr.bucket = {'ipad':34,'ipod':36,'iwatch':27}`
Note: Type of the data is `Series` here

Is there a way I can check for item in bucket (`ipod`) and fetch value (`36`) here?
Also, doing it without a loop is appreciated as I'm doing a column to column compare.

Inputs

```
item    bucket
ipod    {'ipad':34,'ipod':36,'iwatch':27}
ipad    {'ipad':87,'ipod':31,'iwatch':62}
```

Output

```
36
87
```

Comment: How about `fr.bucket[fr.item]`?

Comment: item    bucket
ipod    {'ipad':34,'ipod':36,'iwatch':27}
ipad    {'ipad':87,'ipod':31,'iwatch':22}

result should be
36
87

Comment: @Bazingaa can you check the expected output and help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this, it worked

for i in df.index:

```
#For Bucket
val_bucket=ast.literal_eval(bucket[i])
for key, val in val_bucket.items():
    if my_items[i]== key:
        print ("Value",val)
         break
```

So, I have converted those JSON values (which was in series) to dict and extract the value

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @bazingaa, just use:

```
fr.bucket[fr.item]
```

So get the dictionary key with naming `ipod` then get it's value like above, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# update col1 and col2 to the name of your item and bucket column
col1 = 'item'
col2 = 'bucket'
output = fr.apply(lambda row: row[col2][col1], axis=1)
```

It'll return a pandas series of 36, 87.

**Update:**
In case your items in bucket column have type `str`, try the following first:

```
import ast
fr.loc[:, col2] = fr[col2].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'bucket'", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: TypeError: ('string indices must be integers', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: @Lal So is your column names 'col1' and 'col2' instead of 'bucket' and 'item'?

Answer (score 0):

```
item=['ipod','ipad']
bucket=[{'ipad':34,'ipod':36,'iwatch':27},{'ipad':87,'ipod':31,'iwatch':62}]

result_output=[]    # Defining for output
counter=0           # For initialising the counter through the bucket's elements
for key in item:    # For each row value in column1. Column1 is item.
   temp_bucket=dict(bucket[counter]) # For each column's value,it is as a dictionary
   if key in temp_bucket:   # Checking if the column1's value is present in the dictionary of that row (column2)   
      length_1=len(bucket)-1                 # Need to subtract 1 as python is based on 0 indexing     
      result_output.append(temp_bucket[key]) # Appending each row output to the result list.
      if counter<length_1:                   # Need to check if there is sufficient element is present in column2. Otherwise throw error for index.
         counter=counter+1                  # for checking the next element of column2
```

print(result_output)                           # Output list